# Cancan authorizating operations on nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a form using in which, users can edit their attributes in the User model as well as Photo model. User model has many Photos.

When the user submits the form, the params will have,

```
:user => { :name => "blah blah",
           :photos_attributes => {
                "1" => { "id" => 10, "description" => "Some description"}
           }
         }
```

and I do a `current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])` on the controller.

Everything is working fine. But there is no authorization done on the action. Thereby leaving a security hole. An user can modify any photo of his will by just changing the id passed (in photo_attribtues) in the form post.

How can I check if the current user has permissions(ie. if he is the owner) to alter the photos specified in the photo_attributes using CanCan.

Note: photos_attributes is optional. the params may or may not contain photos_attributes. the solution should not fail if there is no photos_attributes in params[:user]

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: this can't be done (with feasible effort) with CanCan.

Long answer: from CanCan's perspective, you're only dealing with `User` resource that happens to have an attribute called `photos_attributes`. CanCan would have to hook into ActiveRecord's implementation of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in order to scope the referenced association to `Photo.accessible_by(current_ability)` instead of just `Photo` when in a controller context. Ugly!

If you're serious about authorisation and can live without the added comfort of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, the only feasible pragmatic solution for you may be dealing with the extra model yourself (ie. in your controller code).

Answer (score -2):

It's an old question but i ran into same issue

According to `cancan` wiki ([Defining Abilities](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)) it is possible using Hash of conditions, with something like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    #...
    #other abilities
    #...

    # first we check user can only edit his profile (id: user.id)
    # then we check he can only edit his photos
    can :update, User, id: user.id, photos: { id: user.photos_ids }
  end
end
```

Comment: No, this rule means you can only update a User owned by you which has as a photos the photos owned by you. But it does not filter nor authorizes the nested attributes nor prevents a malicious user to update photos that don't belong to him

Answer (score -3):

I assume you defined your routes as follow:

```
resources :users do
  resources :photos
end
```

If so, then, in your `ability.rb` file, you can do:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :manage, Photos, :user_id => user.id
end
```

and it should verify that the photo does belong to the right user.

See: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources

Comment: The question was about nested attributes in models, not nested resources.